# How can you check if a string is a valid double in Swift

Tags: string, swift, double

Say for example you have:

```
var possibleDouble = Double("0.")
```

`possibleDouble` evaluates to `Optional(0.0)`.

In my case `"0."` is not a valid `Double` so `possibleDouble` should be `nil`. Is there a clever way of checking that `"0."` or something in this form is not a valid Double.

EDIT:
A valid number (whether it's an `Int`, `Double`, `Float` or `Decimal`) can be can only be in format N.N or N where N some number. There can be one or more number's before and after the period.

Comment: In **your** case `"0."` is not a valid `Double`. But for Swift it is. So you should list all **your** conditions that must be satisfied by a `String` to be a `Double`. Otherwise how can we answer this question :)

Comment: @appzYourLife updated with the conditions.

Comment: Ok I retracted the close vote.

Comment: You'll want to use a regular expression https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extend `Double` adding a new custom initializer

```
extension Double {
    init?(myCustomFormat:String) {
        guard let
            standardDouble = Double(myCustomFormat),
            firstChar: Character? = myCustomFormat.characters.first,
            lastChar: Character? = myCustomFormat.characters.last
            where firstChar != "." && lastChar != "."
            else { return nil }
        self = standardDouble
    }
}
```

This initializer does create a `Double` only if:

1. the built initializer does succeed and the last
2. the first char of the input `String` is not a `"."`
3. the last char of the input `String` is not a `"."`

### Examples

```
Double(myCustomFormat:"1.") // nil
Double(myCustomFormat:".1") // nil
Double(myCustomFormat:"Hello") // nil
Double(myCustomFormat:"1.1") // 1.1
Double(myCustomFormat:"1") // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found best solution to check whether `string` is convertible to the given type or not. You may test it for `Int` also.

```
if let number = Double("123") {
    print("\(number) is a valid double number")
} else {
    print("Not a valid double number")
}
```

Comment: @Olivier Pons there is nothing wrong with my answer then why you edited it ?. Don't edit someones post to increase your voting.

Comment: Watch what I've corrected. And above all check out my history you'll find out that you're making wrong assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a regular expression:

```
// optionally begin with a minus
let pattern = "^-?\\d+(?:.\\d+)?$"
let value = "10.0"

let validNumber = value.rangeOfString(pattern, options: [.RegularExpressionSearch]) != nil
print(validNumber)
```

If you want to limit the number of integer/decimal digits, replace `+` with `{1,x}` pattern, if you want to limit number of significant digits, just add a `length` check.

Comment: Considered the conditions in the question, this `"10"` should be a valid `Double`.

Comment: @appzYourLife True, overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0**

```
func toDouble(inputString: String) -> Double? {
        return NumberFormatter().number(from: inputString)?.doubleValue
}
```

usage:

```
let myString = "3.0"

//if not a valid Double, return 0
print(toDouble(inputString: myString) ?? "0.0")
```